# Как работать с compound.dll из vbs-скрипта?

Tags: 1с, vbscript

Есть зарегистрированная библиотека Compound.dll (WinXP). В MS Access 2003 она работает. 
При попытке исполнить тоже самое в .vbs-скрипте выскакивает ошибка:

> "Неверная попытка доступа к адресу памяти. Код 800703E6."

Это MS Access - работает:

```
Dim Comp As Object
Set Comp = CreateObject("Amber.Compound")
```

Вот .vbs-файл - не работает:

```
Dim Comp
Set Comp = CreateObject("Amber.Compound")
```

В чем может быть причина и как это исправить?

**Добавлено.**

- в реестре прописалось все правильно: в рунете нашел точно такой же случай и там приведены все ветки реестра, которые надо проверить. У меня все совпало.
- программируется все на одном компе, без сети, один пользователь - это я, имею права администратора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех, кого все-таки интересует вопрос, как же выйти из такого положения: все решилось просто на языке AutoIt, никакой другой скрипт этот объект не брал. Скомпилированная exe-программа вытащила то, что мне надо было. Просто потом исполнил exe-шник в своем Access-2010, где до этого никак не мог получить доступ к объекту Compound:

```
$oMyObj = ObjCreate("Amber.Compound")
$oMyObj.Stream2File("d:\Base1C\1CV7.MD", "Metadata\Main MetaData Stream", "D:\BaseAccess\MyText.txt", 0)
```

Полученный MyText.txt анализируется, как удобно.

Answer (score 0):

Причина может быть:

- в неправильной регистрации библиотеки (проверить реестр),
- в разных правах на исполнение из VBScript и MS Access (проверить запуск c повышением прав (privilege escalation) и от имени другого пользователя (user impersonation)).